# Como mantener la barra de usuario colocada correctamente

Tags: css, laravel-5

Veran, en mi proyecto tengo esta código para la barra de usuario:

```
<header style="width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: 100;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-laravel" style="background-color: #0077FF;">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}"><h2>El Aullido Vespertino</h2></a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    @include("navegaciones.".\App\User::navegacion())
                </ul>
            </div>
            @if(auth()->user() && auth()->user()->activado)
                <img class="card-img-top" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="{{url(auth()->user()->ruta())}}"/>
            @endif
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Al utilizar `position:fixed;` le estoy diciendo al programa que aunque descienda la barra, esta debe mostrarse en la misma zona, pero me da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se come la barra la parte de más arriba, ya que lo que estaba abajo "sube". ¿Como evito este contratiempo?
Por ahora lo he arreglado con unos cuantos `<br>`, pero me gustaria saber si hay otras maneras.

Comment: puedes poner un `margin-top` al elemento que tengas debajo de la barra

Answer (score -1):

En este caso hay dos opciones:

1. Poner `margin-top` al elemento que es solapado por el `nav`.
2. Si el elemento solapado está adentro de un contenedor, ponerle `padding-top` a dicho contenedor.

Comment: Pues no funciona.